# Assigning rvalue to rvalue

Tags: c++, struct

Can I ask why the code below can be compiled without any error?

```cpp
struct Test {
    int num;
};

int main() {
    (Test){.num = 10} = (Test){.num = 20};
    return 0;
}
```

`(Test){.num = 10}` and `(Test){.num = 20}` are rvalue, this is impossible that a rvalue can be assigned to another rvalue. How cpp considers the statement is valid?

PS: the code is compiled using C++11 standard

Comment: This is really no different than `foo(some_string().replace("abc", "123"))`. By the way, the proper C++11 syntax is `Test{10}`. You're using two C features as compiler extensions. In C++20, you can do `Test{.num = 10}`, but still no compound literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how the the special member functions are specified in c++ by default. e.g. `Test` has a synthesized special member function:

```
Test& operator=(Test const &) = default; // if you write it out
```

which can be called on both lvalues and rvalues.

If you want to disallow assignments to rvalues, you have to customize the behavior of the class:

```
struct Test {
    int num;
    Test& operator=(Test const &) & = default;  // lvalues: ok
    Test& operator=(Test const &) && = delete;  // rvalues: error
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zf58EW) in c++20, like the code in your example, but the same principle applies in c++11.

---

Note that for in-built types, the behavior is more sensible, so you can't do this:

```
42 = 5;
3 + 3 = 6;
```

and there's no way to let that compile.